# SAS: formatting multiple proc freq using macros

Tags: macros, sas, formatting

I don't have another analyst on my team at work and have a question about the most efficient way to run several proc freq concurrently.

My goal is to run about 160 different frequencies, and include formatting for all of them. I assume a macro is the fastest way, but I only have experience with basic macros. Below is my thought process assuming the data was already formatted:

```
%macro survey(question, formatA formatB);
proc freq;
table &question;
format &formatA &formatB;
%mend;

%survey (question, formatA, formatB);
```

"question", "formatA" and "formatB" will be strings of data for example:

-"question" would be KCI_1 KCI_2 through KCI_80 
- "formatA" would be KCI_1fmt KCI_2fmt through KCI_80fmt
- "formatB" would be KCI_1fmt. KCI_2fmt. through KCI_80fmt.

Comment: You could just type those TABLES and FORMAT statements directly.  How would making a macro help?

Comment: This really depends on what you're doing with the freq.  Just putting it on the screen?  Making a dataset? What?

Answer (score 0):

Danielle:

You can use macro to assign known formats to variables that are not already formatted.  The rest of the `FREQ` does not have to be macro-ized.

```
* make some survey data with unformatted responses;

data have;
  do respondent_id = 1 to 10000;
     array responses KCI_1-KCI_80;
     do _n_ = 1 to dim(responses);
       responses(_n_) = ceil(4*ranuni(123));
     end;
     output;
  end;
run;

* make some format data for each question;

data responseMeanings;
  length questionID 8 responseValue 8 responseMeaning $50;
  do questionID = 1 to 80;
    fmtname = cats('Q',questionID,'_fmt');
    peg = ranuni (1234); drop peg;
    do responseValue = 1 to 4;
      select;
        when (peg < 0.4) responseMeaning = scan('Never,Seldom,Often,Always', responseValue);
        when (peg < 0.8) responseMeaning = scan('Yes,No,Don''t Ask,Don''t Tell', responseValue);
        otherwise responseMeaning = scan('Nasty,Sour,Sweet,Tasty', responseValue);
      end;
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;

* create a custom format for the responses of each question;

proc format cntlin=responseMeanings(rename=(responseValue=start responseMeaning=label));
run;

* macro to associate variables with the corresponding custom format;

%macro format_each_response;
  %local i;
  format
    %do i = 1 %to 80;
    KCI_&i Q&i._fmt.
    %end;
  ;
%mend;

* compute frequency counts;

proc freq data=have;
  table KCI_1-KCI_80;
  %format_each_response;
run;
```